# Exception is : Already connected in java using Pooling Http Client manager

Tags: java, connection, client-server

My below is to create connection pooling with a server and but my below code is working fine some times and some times gives below error

Exception is : Already connected in java

error trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Already connected
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:655)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:412)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:321)
```

my java code:

```
SslConfigurator sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance()
            .securityProtocol("TLS")
            .keyStoreFile("/path")
            .keyStorePassword("passw")
            .keyStoreType("JKS")
            .trustStoreFile("/path");

    SSLContext sslCtx = sslConfig.createSSLContext();
HostnameVerifier defaultHostnameVerifier = new DefaultHostnameVerifier();
        LayeredConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslConfig.createSSLContext(),
        defaultHostnameVerifier);
        final Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
        .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
        .register("https", sslSocketFactory)
        .build();

        connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER,
                connectionManager);
        client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().withConfig(clientConfig).build();

        Response response = client.target(target).path(path).request(media).post(media);
```